# BeanDefinitionParsingException when trying to import application context from another project

Tags: spring

I am trying to integrate a springProject having different applicationContext (BeanLocation.xml) to a web project having another applicationContext. But I am unable to do so while deploying my web application. I am getting the following error.

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/spring/config/BeanLocations.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/config/BeanLocations.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/config/BeanLocations.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:235)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
```

Here are my different files :

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" metadata-complete="true">
        <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> 
       <!-- Extension of file to be used like localhost:..../helloWorld.jsf -->

   </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>glass-x</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Adding for spring application Context loading -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
<listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
</listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>

faces-config:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
             org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>


</faces-config>
```

applicationContext (of Web-Application):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" /> 


    <import resource="classpath:/spring/config/BeanLocations.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Test.pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mytutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebPrrimeFaces</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>simpleWeb Maven Webapp</name>
    <description>Simple Web Test</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Adding dependency for another project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>SpringExample</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Faces Implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Faces Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces Version 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSP Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces Theme Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>glass-x</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Web dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

HelloWorld:

```
package com.java.view;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.mkyong.stock.bo.StockBo;
import com.mkyong.stock.model.Stock;

@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorld")
@SessionScoped
public class HelloWorld implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6913972022251814607L;

    private String s1 = "Hello World!!";

    @ManagedProperty("#{stockBo}") 
    private StockBo stockBo;

    public StockBo getStockBo() {
        return stockBo;
    }

    public void setStockBo(StockBo stockBo) {
        this.stockBo = stockBo;
    }

    public String getS1() {
        System.out.println(s1);
        return s1;
    }

    public void setS1(String s1) {
        this.s1 = s1;
    }

    Stock stck=stockBo.findByStockCode("7668");



}
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Hello World JSF Example</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>
    <f:view>
        <h:form>

            <h:outputLabel value="#{stck.stockName}" />

        </h:form>

    </f:view>

</h:body>
</html>
```

BeanLocation.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml"/>

    <!-- Auto scan the components -->
    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.mkyong.stock" />

</beans>
```

I have tried all possible combination to import BeanLocation.xml but in vain. 
I help me to find my mistake, I gone through various post in stackoverflow to integrate different applicationContext but I am unable to fix this problem. I am also attaching some of the screen shots of my project.

Comment: I am unable to upload the pictures, do'nt know why it is not getting updated.

Comment: See the message: `path resource [spring/config/BeanLocations.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: `BeanLocation.xml` is not `BeanLocations.xml` see the `s` at the end of the filename

Comment: Sorry but the file name is BeanLocations.xml in actual project.

Comment: When the application is deployed, how is the file structure and is your `BeanLocations.xml` actually where you reference it. Error messages says: `class path resource [spring/config/BeanLocations.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: When the application is deployed it contains the jar of the another project SpringExample . But do you mean to say I need to manually locate the BeaLocations in the buil-path. ? In the build path I am able to see the Dependent class in Test project.

Comment: I am bit confused if there is a way to find the classpath of dependent project application-Context in the imported project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `BeanLocations.xml` file under `src/main/resources/spring/config` folder of your project, and edit the import resource tag as:

```
<import resource="classpath*:/spring/config/BeanLocations.xml"/>
```

or else if it is in same folder where your `applicationContext` file, then edit the import tag as follows:

```
<import resource="BeanLocations.xml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks arpit first one works for me. But then I encounter another issue:     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stockBo': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.mkyong.stock.dao.StockDao com.mkyong.stock.bo.impl.StockBoImpl.stockDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stockDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Comment: My dao releted files are present in BeanLocations.xml, Ideally it should able to inject.

Comment: Open a new question with code inside package `com.mkyong.stock`.